To what extent should we allow questions asking for research about a general subject?
As Seth Rogers posted as a reply to another discussion:

I would hate to see a bunch of "has there ever been a study about x
  influencing y" questions- which is already happening. A quick search
  of the journal databases or even Google scholar can answer most of
  these.

Should these be classified as 'too easy' questions?

If X can be correlated with Y that's a pretty answerable question that might have empirical data backing it up. Even if "easy" that seems like exactly the sort of question we should allow.

A few thoughts:

Question titles should avoid asking for research, such requests should be left to the body of the question (as per this meta point)
In general, it's implicit that good answers should be grounded in the empirical and theoretical scientific literature and provide citations where relevant.
I don't think there should be any general rule such  as "we don't allow questions concerned with relationships between two variables". Understanding the strength and whether there is a relationship between two variables (e.g., intelligence and job performance; caffeine and mood; etc.) is the basis of a lot of science. 
In general, I think there is an issue of scope with many questions. A lot of questions seem a bit too general to yield a deep answer. 
I'd also like to see more questions that appear grounded in an initial understanding of the literature. I guess a good question often shows some initial work and justifies why an answer has not yet been found. E.g., the person asking the question shows that he or she has done a few searches and has learnt what he or she can and now they are stuck.

